# azure iothub device status

Tags: java, azure-iot-hub

getConnectionState() as connected /disconnected depending on the device .if it is sending message i should see connected and if it not sending i should get disconnected .But each time i run the below java Program i am getting status as disconnected irrespective of device is sending messages or not

```
RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.createFromConnectionString(connectionString);
    System.out.println(registryManager.getDevices(new Integer(1000)));
    while(true){
    ArrayList<Device> deviceslist=registryManager.getDevices(new Integer(1000));
    for(Device device:deviceslist)
    {
        /*System.out.println(device.getDeviceId());
        System.out.println(device.getPrimaryKey());
        System.out.println(device.getSecondaryKey());*/
        System.out.println(device.getDeviceId());
        System.out.println(device.getConnectionState());
        /*System.out.println(device.getConnectionStateUpdatedTime());
        System.out.println(device.getLastActivityTime());
        System.out.println(device.getStatusReason());
        System.out.println(device.getStatusUpdatedTime());
        System.out.println(device.getSymmetricKey());
        System.out.println(device.geteTag());
*/  }
    }
```

Comment: Which protocol are you using to send events(http, amqp, mqtt)?

Comment: Have you check the connection state in Device Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

I definitely am seeing otherwise.

I'm creating an simple C# console application using the code below,

```
    static async void QueryDevices()
    {
        RegistryManager manager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        while (true)
        {
            var devices = await manager.GetDevicesAsync(100);
            {
                foreach (var item in devices)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + item.Id + ", " + item.ConnectionState);

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The git here is to always query the whole device list, because the ConnectionState property somehow looks like "static" memebers of the single device client instance, which is not apt-to change even when the actual state changes.

And my output is like below, the "connected" state is when I'm using an java client sample to send message to the IoT Hub.

[image]