# How do I check the status (enabled or disabled) of an IoT device in Azure IoT hub portal through C# code?

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am writing a c# code where I need to check if an IoT device is disabled from the Azure Hub. Please help me with the c# code snippet how can I check it in the code if the device is enabled and disabled. Currently I am testing with 10 devices. Please help.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257697/azure-iothub-device-status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refer to this post([How to disable Enable connection to IoT Hub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63255145/how-to-disable-enable-connection-to-iot-hub)), and I guess we can use below code to test it.

***Offical Doc:***

[1. Device Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.device?view=azure-dotnet)

[2. DeviceStatus Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.devicestatus?view=azure-dotnet)

***Related Post***

[1. How to disable Enable connection to IoT Hub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63255145/how-to-disable-enable-connection-to-iot-hub)

```
    Dictionary<string,int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    // key-value    deviceid--status
    dic.Add("deviceid1",-1);
    ...
    dic.Add("deviceid10", -1);
    // init RegistryManager 
    var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);
    Device device = null;
    foreach (var item in dic)
    {
        device= registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(item.Key);
        if (device != null)
        {
            dic[item.Key] = device.Status.DeviceStatus;
        }
        if (dic[item.Key] == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("deviceid=" + item.Key + "  ,  device not found");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("deviceid=" + item.Key + "  ,  status=" + (dic[item.Key] == 1 ? "Disabled" : "Enabled"));
        }
    }
```

[image]